# Ramping constraint in linear scheduling program in PuLP

Tags: python, scheduling, pulp

I am trying to write a LP in PuLP which minimizes the electricity costs of a nitrogen blending process. The produced nitrogen can be either directly used for the blending or can be stored and extracted at a later stage. With this flexibility, the blending process can be optimized based on the day ahead electricity costs.

I have created a dictionary with all the possible configurations for the plant with the corresponding electricity consumption, storage application and configuration of the three air separation units. From this dictionary, I then create a nested dictionary based on the forecasted nitrogen demand. Each primary key represents a timestage of 1 hour for the next day and the nested dictionary contains all the possible configurations for that timestage (which are the configurations which at least meet the forecasted demand of that hour).

So the nested dictionary has the following structure:

```
d = {t : { cfg_key : [production value (total production of ASUs in m3/hr), 
consumption value (MW), storage application (i.e. extraction or injection in m3/hr),(ASU 1, ASU 2, ASU 3)}}

e.g.: { 0 : { 135 : [(0, 0, 48000), 14.76, -115000,], 137 : [.....], ....etc. }}
```

if you need more details on this dictionary and how it was made, please ask I will add it. I've currently left it out to be more concise.

I then wrote the following LP in PuLP. This code selects one possible configuration for each timeslot, while meeting production and storage constraints.

```
from pulp import *

d = sols_cands
set_ASU = range(0,3)
M = 60000

#----Program Initialization--------------------------------------------------------------
lp_problem = LpProblem("SchedulingProgram", LpMinimize)

#----Variables---------------------------------------------------------------------------
var = {}       # Binary variable for each possible config to select

for t in d:
    var[t] = {}
    for cfg in d[t]:
        var[t][cfg] = LpVariable(f"x_{t}_{cfg}", 0, 1, LpBinary)

#----Objective function------------------------------------------------------------------
objective = sum([d[t][cfg][1] * var[t][cfg] * energy_prices[t] 
                      for t in var.keys() for cfg in var[t].keys()])

lp_problem.setObjective(objective)

#----Constraints-------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Constraint which ensures only one configuration is selected for each timeslot
for t in var.keys():
    lp_problem += sum([var[t][cfg] for cfg in var[t].keys()]) == 1

# Constraint to zero out the total storage utilization (extraction and injection) over the day
lp_problem += sum([d[t][cfg][2]*var[t][cfg] for t in var.keys() 
                       for cfg in var[t].keys()]) == 0
        

# Solve the LP problem
lp_problem.solve()

# Print the solution
for t in var.keys():
    for cfg in d[t].keys():
        if var[t][cfg].varValue == 1:
            print(f"Timeslot {t} : Energy Price {energy_prices[t]} \
                    : N2 Demand {n2_demand[t]} : Config {t} : {d[t][cfg]}")

print(f"Total energy costs are: {lp_problem.objective.value()}")
print(f"Status: {lp_problem.status}")
```

Then I've tried to add a constraint which limits the change in production of the ASUs to 9000 for sequential timeslots. I've added the following variable to track the status of the ASU and constraints.

```
ASU_status = {}    # Binary variable to track whether an ASU is on or off
for t in d:
    ASU_status[t] = {asu: LpVariable(f"z_{t}_{asu}", 0, 1, LpBinary) 
                            for asu in set_ASU}
    
for t in set_T:
    for cfg in d[t]:
        for asu in set_ASU:
            lp_problem += ASU_bin[t][asu] * M >= var[t][cfg]* d[t][cfg][0][asu]
        lp_problem += ASU_bin[t][asu] <= var[t][cfg]* d[t][cfg][0][asu]
          
        
for t in range(1,24):
    for cfg in d[t]:
        for p_cfg in d[t-1]:
            for asu in set_ASU:
                ASU_change = var[t][cfg] * d[t][cfg][0][asu] - var[t-1][p_cfg] * d[t-1][p_cfg][0][asu]
                lp_problem += ASU_change  <= ASU_status[t][asu] * 9000 + \
                                             (2 - ASU_status[t-1][asu] - ASU_status[t][asu])* M
                lp_problem += ASU_change >= - ASU_status[t][asu] * 9000 - \
                                              (2 - ASU_status[t-1][asu]- ASU_status[t][asu])* M
```

---

Part of config dictionary {config: [(ASU config), E-cons, Injection or extraction value]:

```
{0: [(0, 0, 0), 0.0, 0],
 1: [(0, 0, 0), 0.0, -10000],
 2: [(0, 0, 0), 0.0, -15000],
 3: [(0, 0, 0), 0.0, -20000],
 4: [(0, 0, 0), 0.0, -25000],
 5: [(0, 0, 0), 0.0, -30000],
 6: [(0, 0, 0), 0.0, -35000],
 7: [(0, 0, 0), 0.0, -40000],
 8: [(0, 0, 0), 0.0, -45000],
 9: [(0, 0, 0), 0.0, -50000],
 10: [(0, 0, 0), 0.0, -55000],
 11: [(0, 0, 0), 0.0, -60000],
 12: [(0, 0, 0), 0.0, -65000],
 13: [(0, 0, 0), 0.0, -70000],
 14: [(0, 0, 0), 0.0, -75000],
 15: [(0, 0, 0), 0.0, -80000],
 16: [(0, 0, 0), 0.0, -85000],
 17: [(0, 0, 0), 0.0, -90000],
 18: [(0, 0, 0), 0.0, -95000],
 19: [(0, 0, 0), 0.0, -100000],
 20: [(0, 0, 0), 0.0, -105000],
 21: [(0, 0, 0), 0.0, -110000],
 22: [(0, 0, 0), 0.0, -115000],
 23: [(0, 0, 0), 0.0, -120000],
 24: [(0, 0, 0), 0.0, -125000],
 25: [(0, 0, 0), 0.0, -130000],
 26: [(0, 0, 0), 0.0, -135000],
 27: [(0, 0, 0), 0.0, -140000],
 28: [(0, 0, 0), 0.0, -145000],
 29: [(0, 0, 0), 0.0, -150000],
 30: [(0, 0, 0), 0.0, -155000],
 31: [(0, 0, 0), 0.0, -160000],
 32: [(0, 0, 0), 0.0, -165000],
 33: [(0, 0, 0), 0.0, -170000],
 34: [(0, 0, 0), 0.0, -175000],
 35: [(0, 0, 0), 0.0, -180000],
 36: [(0, 0, 0), 0.0, -185000],
 37: [(0, 0, 0), 0.0, -190000],
 38: [(0, 0, 42000), 10.815, 0],
 39: [(0, 0, 42000), 10.815, -10000],
 40: [(0, 0, 42000), 10.815, -15000],
 41: [(0, 0, 42000), 10.815, -20000],
 42: [(0, 0, 42000), 10.815, -25000],
 43: [(0, 0, 42000), 10.815, -30000],
 44: [(0, 0, 42000), 10.815, -35000],
 45: [(0, 0, 42000), 10.815, -40000],
 46: [(0, 0, 42000), 10.815, -45000],
 47: [(0, 0, 42000), 10.815, -50000],
 48: [(0, 0, 42000), 10.815, -55000],
 49: [(0, 0, 42000), 10.815, -60000],
 50: [(0, 0, 42000), 10.815, -65000],
 51: [(0, 0, 42000), 10.815, -70000],
 52: [(0, 0, 42000), 10.815, -75000],
 53: [(0, 0, 42000), 10.815, -80000],
 54: [(0, 0, 42000), 10.815, -85000],
 55: [(0, 0, 42000), 10.815, -90000],
 56: [(0, 0, 42000), 10.815, -95000],
 57: [(0, 0, 42000), 10.815, -100000],
 58: [(0, 0, 42000), 10.815, -105000],
 59: [(0, 0, 42000), 10.815, -110000],
 60: [(0, 0, 42000), 10.815, -115000],
 61: [(0, 0, 42000), 10.815, -120000],
 62: [(0, 0, 42000), 10.815, -125000],
 63: [(0, 0, 42000), 10.815, -130000],
 64: [(0, 0, 42000), 10.815, -135000],
 65: [(0, 0, 42000), 10.815, -140000],
 66: [(0, 0, 42000), 10.815, -145000],
 67: [(0, 0, 44000), 11.293, 0],
 68: [(0, 0, 44000), 11.293, -10000],
 69: [(0, 0, 44000), 11.293, -15000],
 70: [(0, 0, 44000), 11.293, -20000],
 71: [(0, 0, 44000), 11.293, -25000],
 72: [(0, 0, 44000), 11.293, -30000],
 73: [(0, 0, 44000), 11.293, -35000],
 74: [(0, 0, 44000), 11.293, -40000],
 75: [(0, 0, 44000), 11.293, -45000],
 76: [(0, 0, 44000), 11.293, -50000],
 77: [(0, 0, 44000), 11.293, -55000],
 78: [(0, 0, 44000), 11.293, -60000],
 79: [(0, 0, 44000), 11.293, -65000],
 80: [(0, 0, 44000), 11.293, -70000],
 81: [(0, 0, 44000), 11.293, -75000],
 82: [(0, 0, 44000), 11.293, -80000],
 83: [(0, 0, 44000), 11.293, -85000],
 84: [(0, 0, 44000), 11.293, -90000],
 85: [(0, 0, 44000), 11.293, -95000],
 86: [(0, 0, 44000), 11.293, -100000],
 87: [(0, 0, 44000), 11.293, -105000],
 88: [(0, 0, 44000), 11.293, -110000],
 89: [(0, 0, 44000), 11.293, -115000],
 90: [(0, 0, 44000), 11.293, -120000],
 91: [(0, 0, 44000), 11.293, -125000],
 92: [(0, 0, 44000), 11.293, -130000],
 93: [(0, 0, 44000), 11.293, -135000],
 94: [(0, 0, 44000), 11.293, -140000],
 95: [(0, 0, 44000), 11.293, -145000],
 96: [(0, 0, 46000), 11.772, 0],
 97: [(0, 0, 46000), 11.772, -10000],
 98: [(0, 0, 46000), 11.772, -15000],
 99: [(0, 0, 46000), 11.772, -20000],
 100: [(0, 0, 46000), 11.772, -25000],
 101: [(0, 0, 46000), 11.772, -30000],
 102: [(0, 0, 46000), 11.772, -35000],
 103: [(0, 0, 46000), 11.772, -40000],
 104: [(0, 0, 46000), 11.772, -45000],
 105: [(0, 0, 46000), 11.772, -50000],
 106: [(0, 0, 46000), 11.772, -55000],
 107: [(0, 0, 46000), 11.772, -60000],
 108: [(0, 0, 46000), 11.772, -65000],
 109: [(0, 0, 46000), 11.772, -70000],
 110: [(0, 0, 46000), 11.772, -75000],
 111: [(0, 0, 46000), 11.772, -80000],
 112: [(0, 0, 46000), 11.772, -85000],
 113: [(0, 0, 46000), 11.772, -90000],
 114: [(0, 0, 46000), 11.772, -95000],
 115: [(0, 0, 46000), 11.772, -100000],
 116: [(0, 0, 46000), 11.772, -105000],
 117: [(0, 0, 46000), 11.772, -110000],
 118: [(0, 0, 46000), 11.772, -115000],
 119: [(0, 0, 46000), 11.772, -120000],
 120: [(0, 0, 46000), 11.772, -125000],
 121: [(0, 0, 46000), 11.772, -130000],
 122: [(0, 0, 46000), 11.772, -135000],
 123: [(0, 0, 46000), 11.772, -140000],
 124: [(0, 0, 48000), 12.25, 0],
 125: [(0, 0, 48000), 12.25, -10000],
 126: [(0, 0, 48000), 12.25, -15000],
 127: [(0, 0, 48000), 12.25, -20000],
 128: [(0, 0, 48000), 12.25, -25000],
 129: [(0, 0, 48000), 12.25, -30000],
 130: [(0, 0, 48000), 12.25, -35000],
 131: [(0, 0, 48000), 12.25, -40000],
 132: [(0, 0, 48000), 12.25, -45000],
 133: [(0, 0, 48000), 12.25, -50000],
 134: [(0, 0, 48000), 12.25, -55000],
 135: [(0, 0, 48000), 12.25, -60000],
 136: [(0, 0, 48000), 12.25, -65000],
 137: [(0, 0, 48000), 12.25, -70000],
 138: [(0, 0, 48000), 12.25, -75000],
 139: [(0, 0, 48000), 12.25, -80000],
 140: [(0, 0, 48000), 12.25, -85000],
 141: [(0, 0, 48000), 12.25, -90000],
 142: [(0, 0, 48000), 12.25, -95000],
 143: [(0, 0, 48000), 12.25, -100000],
 144: [(0, 0, 48000), 12.25, -105000],
 145: [(0, 0, 48000), 12.25, -110000],
 146: [(0, 0, 48000), 12.25, -115000],
 147: [(0, 0, 48000), 12.25, -120000],
 148: [(0, 0, 48000), 12.25, -125000],
 149: [(0, 0, 48000), 12.25, -130000],
 150: [(0, 0, 48000), 12.25, -135000],
 151: [(0, 0, 48000), 12.25, -140000],
 152: [(0, 0, 50000), 12.728, 0],
 153: [(0, 0, 50000), 12.728, -10000],
 154: [(0, 0, 50000), 12.728, -15000],
 155: [(0, 0, 50000), 12.728, -20000],
 156: [(0, 0, 50000), 12.728, -25000],
 157: [(0, 0, 50000), 12.728, -30000],
 158: [(0, 0, 50000), 12.728, -35000],
 159: [(0, 0, 50000), 12.728, -40000],
 160: [(0, 0, 50000), 12.728, -45000],
 161: [(0, 0, 50000), 12.728, -50000],
 162: [(0, 0, 50000), 12.728, -55000],
 163: [(0, 0, 50000), 12.728, -60000],
 164: [(0, 0, 50000), 12.728, -65000],
 165: [(0, 0, 50000), 12.728, -70000],
 166: [(0, 0, 50000), 12.728, -75000],
 167: [(0, 0, 50000), 12.728, -80000],
 168: [(0, 0, 50000), 12.728, -85000],
 169: [(0, 0, 50000), 12.728, -90000],
 170: [(0, 0, 50000), 12.728, -95000],
 171: [(0, 0, 50000), 12.728, -100000],
 172: [(0, 0, 50000), 12.728, -105000],
 173: [(0, 0, 50000), 12.728, -110000],
 174: [(0, 0, 50000), 12.728, -115000],
 175: [(0, 0, 50000), 12.728, -120000],
 176: [(0, 0, 50000), 12.728, -125000],
 177: [(0, 0, 50000), 12.728, -130000],
 178: [(0, 0, 50000), 12.728, -135000],
 179: [(0, 0, 50000), 12.728, -140000],
 180: [(0, 0, 52000), 13.207, 0],
 181: [(0, 0, 52000), 13.207, -10000],
 182: [(0, 0, 52000), 13.207, -15000],
 183: [(0, 0, 52000), 13.207, -20000],
 184: [(0, 0, 52000), 13.207, -25000],
 185: [(0, 0, 52000), 13.207, -30000],
 186: [(0, 0, 52000), 13.207, -35000],
 187: [(0, 0, 52000), 13.207, -40000],
 188: [(0, 0, 52000), 13.207, -45000],
 189: [(0, 0, 52000), 13.207, -50000],
 190: [(0, 0, 52000), 13.207, -55000],
 191: [(0, 0, 52000), 13.207, -60000],
 192: [(0, 0, 52000), 13.207, -65000],
 193: [(0, 0, 52000), 13.207, -70000],
 194: [(0, 0, 52000), 13.207, -75000],
 195: [(0, 0, 52000), 13.207, -80000],
 196: [(0, 0, 52000), 13.207, -85000],
 197: [(0, 0, 52000), 13.207, -90000],
 198: [(0, 0, 52000), 13.207, -95000],
 199: [(0, 0, 52000), 13.207, -100000],
 200: [(0, 0, 52000), 13.207, -105000],
 201: [(0, 0, 52000), 13.207, -110000],
 202: [(0, 0, 52000), 13.207, -115000],
 203: [(0, 0, 52000), 13.207, -120000],
 204: [(0, 0, 52000), 13.207, -125000],
 205: [(0, 0, 52000), 13.207, -130000],
 206: [(0, 0, 52000), 13.207, -135000],
 207: [(0, 0, 54000), 13.685, 0],
 208: [(0, 0, 54000), 13.685, -10000],
 209: [(0, 0, 54000), 13.685, -15000],
 210: [(0, 0, 54000), 13.685, -20000],
 211: [(0, 0, 54000), 13.685, -25000],
 212: [(0, 0, 54000), 13.685, -30000],
 213: [(0, 0, 54000), 13.685, -35000],
 214: [(0, 0, 54000), 13.685, -40000],
 215: [(0, 0, 54000), 13.685, -45000],
 216: [(0, 0, 54000), 13.685, -50000],
 217: [(0, 0, 54000), 13.685, -55000],
 218: [(0, 0, 54000), 13.685, -60000],
 219: [(0, 0, 54000), 13.685, -65000],
 220: [(0, 0, 54000), 13.685, -70000],
 221: [(0, 0, 54000), 13.685, -75000],
 222: [(0, 0, 54000), 13.685, -80000],
 223: [(0, 0, 54000), 13.685, -85000],
 224: [(0, 0, 54000), 13.685, -90000],
 225: [(0, 0, 54000), 13.685, -95000],
 226: [(0, 0, 54000), 13.685, -100000],
 227: [(0, 0, 54000), 13.685, -105000],
 228: [(0, 0, 54000), 13.685, -110000],
 229: [(0, 0, 54000), 13.685, -115000],
 230: [(0, 0, 54000), 13.685, -120000],
 231: [(0, 0, 54000), 13.685, -125000],
 232: [(0, 0, 54000), 13.685, -130000],
 233: [(0, 0, 54000), 13.685, -135000],
 234: [(0, 0, 56000), 14.163, 0],
 235: [(0, 0, 56000), 14.163, -10000],
 236: [(0, 0, 56000), 14.163, -15000],
 237: [(0, 0, 56000), 14.163, -20000],
 238: [(0, 0, 56000), 14.163, -25000],
 239: [(0, 0, 56000), 14.163, -30000],
 240: [(0, 0, 56000), 14.163, -35000],
 241: [(0, 0, 56000), 14.163, -40000],
 242: [(0, 0, 56000), 14.163, -45000],
 243: [(0, 0, 56000), 14.163, -50000],
 244: [(0, 0, 56000), 14.163, -55000],
 245: [(0, 0, 56000), 14.163, -60000],
 246: [(0, 0, 56000), 14.163, -65000],
 247: [(0, 0, 56000), 14.163, -70000],
 248: [(0, 0, 56000), 14.163, -75000],
 249: [(0, 0, 56000), 14.163, -80000],
 250: [(0, 0, 56000), 14.163, -85000],
 251: [(0, 0, 56000), 14.163, -90000],
 252: [(0, 0, 56000), 14.163, -95000],
 253: [(0, 0, 56000), 14.163, -100000],
 254: [(0, 0, 56000), 14.163, -105000],
 255: [(0, 0, 56000), 14.163, -110000],
 256: [(0, 0, 56000), 14.163, -115000],
 257: [(0, 0, 56000), 14.163, -120000],
 258: [(0, 0, 56000), 14.163, -125000],
 259: [(0, 0, 56000), 14.163, -130000],
 260: [(0, 0, 58000), 14.642, 0],
 261: [(0, 0, 58000), 14.642, -10000],
 262: [(0, 0, 58000), 14.642, -15000],
 263: [(0, 0, 58000), 14.642, -20000],
 264: [(0, 0, 58000), 14.642, -25000],
 265: [(0, 0, 58000), 14.642, -30000],
 266: [(0, 0, 58000), 14.642, -35000],
 267: [(0, 0, 58000), 14.642, -40000],
 268: [(0, 0, 58000), 14.642, -45000],
 269: [(0, 0, 58000), 14.642, -50000],
 270: [(0, 0, 58000), 14.642, -55000],
 271: [(0, 0, 58000), 14.642, -60000],
 272: [(0, 0, 58000), 14.642, -65000],
 273: [(0, 0, 58000), 14.642, -70000],
 274: [(0, 0, 58000), 14.642, -75000],
 275: [(0, 0, 58000), 14.642, -80000],
 276: [(0, 0, 58000), 14.642, -85000],
 277: [(0, 0, 58000), 14.642, -90000],
 278: [(0, 0, 58000), 14.642, -95000],
 279: [(0, 0, 58000), 14.642, -100000],
 280: [(0, 0, 58000), 14.642, -105000],
 281: [(0, 0, 58000), 14.642, -110000],
 282: [(0, 0, 58000), 14.642, -115000],
 283: [(0, 0, 58000), 14.642, -120000],
 284: [(0, 0, 58000), 14.642, -125000],
 285: [(0, 0, 58000), 14.642, -130000],
 286: [(0, 0, 58000), 18.212, 58000],
 287: [(0, 0, 60000), 15.12, 0],
 288: [(0, 0, 60000), 15.12, -10000],
 289: [(0, 0, 60000), 15.12, -15000],
 290: [(0, 0, 60000), 15.12, -20000],
 291: [(0, 0, 60000), 15.12, -25000],
 292: [(0, 0, 60000), 15.12, -30000],
 293: [(0, 0, 60000), 15.12, -35000],
 294: [(0, 0, 60000), 15.12, -40000],
 295: [(0, 0, 60000), 15.12, -45000],
 296: [(0, 0, 60000), 15.12, -50000],
 297: [(0, 0, 60000), 15.12, -55000],
 298: [(0, 0, 60000), 15.12, -60000],
 299: [(0, 0, 60000), 15.12, -65000],
 300: [(0, 0, 60000), 15.12, -70000],
 301: [(0, 0, 60000), 15.12, -75000],
 302: [(0, 0, 60000), 15.12, -80000],
 303: [(0, 0, 60000), 15.12, -85000],
 304: [(0, 0, 60000), 15.12, -90000],
 305: [(0, 0, 60000), 15.12, -95000],
 306: [(0, 0, 60000), 15.12, -100000],
 307: [(0, 0, 60000), 15.12, -105000],
 308: [(0, 0, 60000), 15.12, -110000],
 309: [(0, 0, 60000), 15.12, -115000],
 310: [(0, 0, 60000), 15.12, -120000],
 311: [(0, 0, 60000), 15.12, -125000],
 312: [(0, 0, 60000), 15.12, -130000],
 313: [(0, 0, 60000), 18.69, 58000],
 314: [(0, 0, 60000), 18.87, 60000],
 315: [(0, 42000, 42000), 21.63, 0],
 316: [(0, 42000, 42000), 21.63, -10000],
 317: [(0, 42000, 42000), 21.63, -15000],
 318: [(0, 42000, 42000), 21.63, -20000],
 319: [(0, 42000, 42000), 21.63, -25000],
 320: [(0, 42000, 42000), 21.63, -30000],
 321: [(0, 42000, 42000), 21.63, -35000],
 322: [(0, 42000, 42000), 21.63, -40000],
 323: [(0, 42000, 42000), 21.63, -45000],
 324: [(0, 42000, 42000), 21.63, -50000],
 325: [(0, 42000, 42000), 21.63, -55000],
 326: [(0, 42000, 42000), 21.63, -60000],
 327: [(0, 42000, 42000), 21.63, -65000],
 328: [(0, 42000, 42000), 21.63, -70000],
 329: [(0, 42000, 42000), 21.63, -75000],
 330: [(0, 42000, 42000), 21.63, -80000],
 331: [(0, 42000, 42000), 21.63, -85000],
 332: [(0, 42000, 42000), 21.63, -90000],
 333: [(0, 42000, 42000), 21.63, -95000],
 334: [(0, 42000, 42000), 21.63, -100000],
 335: [(0, 42000, 42000), 21.63, -105000],
 336: [(0, 42000, 42000), 25.2, 58000],
 337: [(0, 42000, 42000), 25.38, 60000],
 338: [(0, 42000, 42000), 25.56, 65000],
 339: [(0, 42000, 42000), 25.74, 70000],
 340: [(0, 42000, 42000), 25.92, 75000],
 341: [(0, 42000, 42000), 26.1, 80000],
 342: [(0, 42000, 44000), 22.108, 0],
 343: [(0, 42000, 44000), 22.108, -10000],
 344: [(0, 42000, 44000), 22.108, -15000],
 345: [(0, 42000, 44000), 22.108, -20000],
 346: [(0, 42000, 44000), 22.108, -25000],
 347: [(0, 42000, 44000), 22.108, -30000],
 348: [(0, 42000, 44000), 22.108, -35000],
 349: [(0, 42000, 44000), 22.108, -40000],
 350: [(0, 42000, 44000), 22.108, -45000],
 351: [(0, 42000, 44000), 22.108, -50000],
 352: [(0, 42000, 44000), 22.108, -55000],
 353: [(0, 42000, 44000), 22.108, -60000],
 354: [(0, 42000, 44000), 22.108, -65000],
 355: [(0, 42000, 44000), 22.108, -70000],
 356: [(0, 42000, 44000), 22.108, -75000],
 357: [(0, 42000, 44000), 22.108, -80000],
 358: [(0, 42000, 44000), 22.108, -85000],
 359: [(0, 42000, 44000), 22.108, -90000],
 360: [(0, 42000, 44000), 22.108, -95000],
 361: [(0, 42000, 44000), 22.108, -100000],
 362: [(0, 42000, 44000), 25.678, 58000],
 363: [(0, 42000, 44000), 25.858, 60000],
 364: [(0, 42000, 44000), 26.038, 65000],
 365: [(0, 42000, 44000), 26.218, 70000],
 366: [(0, 42000, 44000), 26.398, 75000],
 367: [(0, 42000, 44000), 26.578, 80000],
 368: [(0, 42000, 44000), 26.758, 85000],
 369: [(0, 44000, 44000), 22.586, 0],
 370: [(0, 44000, 44000), 22.586, -10000],
 371: [(0, 44000, 44000), 22.586, -15000],
 372: [(0, 44000, 44000), 22.586, -20000],
 373: [(0, 44000, 44000), 22.586, -25000],
 374: [(0, 44000, 44000), 22.586, -30000],
 375: [(0, 44000, 44000), 22.586, -35000],
 376: [(0, 44000, 44000), 22.586, -40000],
 377: [(0, 44000, 44000), 22.586, -45000],
 378: [(0, 44000, 44000), 22.586, -50000],
 379: [(0, 44000, 44000), 22.586, -55000],
 380: [(0, 44000, 44000), 22.586, -60000],
 381: [(0, 44000, 44000), 22.586, -65000],
 382: [(0, 44000, 44000), 22.586, -70000],
 383: [(0, 44000, 44000), 22.586, -75000],
 384: [(0, 44000, 44000), 22.586, -80000],
 385: [(0, 44000, 44000), 22.586, -85000],
 386: [(0, 44000, 44000), 22.586, -90000],
 387: [(0, 44000, 44000), 22.586, -95000],
 388: [(0, 44000, 44000), 22.586, -100000],
 389: [(0, 44000, 44000), 26.156, 58000],
 390: [(0, 44000, 44000), 26.336, 60000],
 391: [(0, 44000, 44000), 26.516, 65000],
 392: [(0, 44000, 44000), 26.696, 70000],
 393: [(0, 44000, 44000), 26.876, 75000],
 394: [(0, 44000, 44000), 27.056, 80000],
 395: [(0, 44000, 44000), 27.236, 85000],
 396: [(0, 42000, 48000), 23.065, 0],
 397: [(0, 42000, 48000), 23.065, -10000],
 398: [(0, 42000, 48000), 23.065, -15000],
 399: [(0, 42000, 48000), 23.065, -20000],
 400: [(0, 42000, 48000), 23.065, -25000],
 401: [(0, 42000, 48000), 23.065, -30000],
 402: [(0, 42000, 48000), 23.065, -35000],
 403: [(0, 42000, 48000), 23.065, -40000],
 404: [(0, 42000, 48000), 23.065, -45000],
 405: [(0, 42000, 48000), 23.065, -50000],
 406: [(0, 42000, 48000), 23.065, -55000],
 407: [(0, 42000, 48000), 23.065, -60000],
 408: [(0, 42000, 48000), 23.065, -65000],
 409: [(0, 42000, 48000), 23.065, -70000],
 410: [(0, 42000, 48000), 23.065, -75000],
 411: [(0, 42000, 48000), 23.065, -80000],
 412: [(0, 42000, 48000), 23.065, -85000],
 413: [(0, 42000, 48000), 23.065, -90000],
 414: [(0, 42000, 48000), 23.065, -95000],
 415: [(0, 42000, 48000), 23.065, -100000],
 416: [(0, 42000, 48000), 26.635, 58000],
 417: [(0, 42000, 48000), 26.815, 60000],
 418: [(0, 42000, 48000), 26.995, 65000],
 419: [(0, 42000, 48000), 27.175, 70000],
 420: [(0, 42000, 48000), 27.355, 75000],
 421: [(0, 42000, 48000), 27.535, 80000],
 422: [(0, 42000, 48000), 27.715, 85000],
 423: [(0, 42000, 48000), 27.895, 90000],
 424: [(0, 42000, 50000), 23.543, 0],
 425: [(0, 42000, 50000), 23.543, -10000],
 426: [(0, 42000, 50000), 23.543, -15000],
 427: [(0, 42000, 50000), 23.543, -20000],
 428: [(0, 42000, 50000), 23.543, -25000],
 429: [(0, 42000, 50000), 23.543, -30000],
 430: [(0, 42000, 50000), 23.543, -35000],
 431: [(0, 42000, 50000), 23.543, -40000],
 432: [(0, 42000, 50000), 23.543, -45000],
 433: [(0, 42000, 50000), 23.543, -50000],
 434: [(0, 42000, 50000), 23.543, -55000],
 435: [(0, 42000, 50000), 23.543, -60000],
 436: [(0, 42000, 50000), 23.543, -65000],
 437: [(0, 42000, 50000), 23.543, -70000],
 438: [(0, 42000, 50000), 23.543, -75000],
 439: [(0, 42000, 50000), 23.543, -80000],
 440: [(0, 42000, 50000), 23.543, -85000],
 441: [(0, 42000, 50000), 23.543, -90000],
 442: [(0, 42000, 50000), 23.543, -95000],
 443: [(0, 42000, 50000), 27.113, 58000],
 444: [(0, 42000, 50000), 27.293, 60000],
 445: [(0, 42000, 50000), 27.473, 65000],
 446: [(0, 42000, 50000), 27.653, 70000],
 447: [(0, 42000, 50000), 27.833, 75000],
 448: [(0, 42000, 50000), 28.013, 80000],
```

The current code I have is this:

```
import pulp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pickle
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


#----DATA--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

time_steps = list(range(0,24))
asus = [0, 1, 2]

#----Nitrogen demand forecast------------------------------------------------------------
n2_demand = [121548, 121453, 121537, 121715, 119228, 118547, 118675, 115909, 108003, 103060, 100284, 99211, 99915, 103157, 102453, 
            106371, 107764, 117624, 123072, 123492, 120911, 113903, 107971, 107243]
energy_prices = [130.12, 128.01, 121.34, 114.94, 119.04, 132.98, 172.34, 190.85, 190, 176.92, 160.10, 151.80, 145.06, 132.50, 129.71,
                 128.53, 132.50, 165.21, 177.48, 191.34, 182.87, 163.08, 141.30, 131.18]
#----Import of configuration dictinary---------------------------------------------------
with open('saved_ConfigDict.pkl', 'rb') as f:                                       # Dictionary containing all the configurations
    cfg_d = pickle.load(f)


prob = pulp.LpProblem("Nitrogen_Optimization", pulp.LpMinimize)     


t_c = [ (t, c) for t in time_steps for c in cfg_d ]                                         # Time-Configurations combinations

t_a = [ (t, a) for t in time_steps for a in asus ]                                          # Time-ASU combinations

tot_prod = {c:sum(vals[0]) for c, vals in cfg_d.items()}                                # Total production value of the 3 ASUs

#----Variables---------------------------------------------------------------------------
run_cfg = pulp.LpVariable.dicts('run', t_c, cat='Binary')                                   # Run configuration c in timeslot t
asu_output_increase = pulp.LpVariable.dicts('increase_asu', t_a, cat='Binary')              # ASU a changes status in timeslot t
ASU_on = {(t, asu): pulp.LpVariable(cat='Binary', name=f'ASU_on_{asu}_{t}')
            for asu in asus for t in time_steps}

#----Objective---------------------------------------------------------------------------

obj = pulp.lpSum(cfg_d[c][1] * run_cfg[t, c] * energy_prices[t] for t, c in t_c)
prob.setObjective(obj)

#----Constraints-------------------------------------------------------------------------

for t in time_steps:

    
    tot_n2 = pulp.lpSum(tot_prod[c] * run_cfg[t, c] - cfg_d[c][2] * run_cfg[t, c] for c in cfg_d)      # Constraint 1: Ensure demand is met in each
    prob += tot_n2 >= n2_demand[t]                                                      # timestep 


    prob += sum(run_cfg[t, c] for c in cfg_d.keys()) == 1                                   # Constraint 2: Exactly one config is run in 
                                                                                            # each timestep 
ramp_limit = 9000
                                                                                               

    
                                                                 

    # Constraint 3: Capture and limit change in ASUs
for t in time_steps[1:]:
    for asu in asus:  
        prod_this_step = pulp.lpSum(cfg_d[c][0][asu] * run_cfg[t, c] for c in cfg_d)
        prod_last_step = pulp.lpSum(cfg_d[c][0][asu] * run_cfg[t-1, c] for c in cfg_d)
        ASU_change = prod_this_step - prod_last_step
        prob += prod_this_step <= M * ASU_on[t, asu]
        prob += prod_this_step >= 0.001 * ASU_on[t, asu]
        prob += prod_last_step <= M * ASU_on[t-1, asu]
        prob += prod_last_step >= 0.001 * ASU_on[t-1, asu]
                  
        prob += ASU_change <= ramp_limit + (2 - ASU_on[t, asu] - ASU_on[t-1, asu]) * M
        prob += ASU_change >= -ramp_limit - (2 - ASU_on[t, asu] - ASU_on[t-1, asu]) * M

prob += pulp.lpSum(run_cfg[t, c] * cfg_d[c][2] for t in time_steps for c in cfg_d) == 0            # Constraint 4: Limit the utilization of the storage

#----Results-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
prob.solve()

for v in prob.variables():
    if v.varValue > 0:
        print(v.name, "=", v.varValue)
```

Comment: Your mode is very confusing and I think you should do some housekeeping and edit your question.  It isn't clear why you have all of your data balled up in 1 dictionary.  I think it should be separate for clarity.  Storage costs/production values, etc. **don't** depend on the configuration, right?  or do they?  Your variables are unclear.  `var`?  `ASU_bin`?  I'd rename them, or at least put some comments in your code to say what they mean.

Comment: Lastly, the relationship between ASU configurations and what is produced and what is going on with `ASU_bin` is unclear.  If you have 3 units that can be on or off, then just use 3 binary variables for them in each tilmestep.  If there are some set of "lineups" involving all 3, which seems implied, then there should be a set of acceptable lineups and each lineup should have a corresponding output, right?  I would expect that in a separate dictionary and not co-mingled with `time` unless the configurations change over time...etc.

Comment: Hi AirSquid, thanks for your response and apologies for my vague question. I've combined the data in one dictionary, because it is interrelated; the production value is the total of the three ASUs in m3/hr and the storage application represents either injection or extraction. The electricity consumption is dependent on these values and that is why I have linked them in a dictionary. The ASU configuration is the optimal configuration for the production value (electricity consumption wise).

Comment: That is what I tried to code with ASU_bin (now changed to ASU_status), to track the on or off status of the ASUs in each timestep and use it to limit the change in production of each ASU to 9000. I now see that I haven't correctly done that. The configuration of the ASU can change in each timestep. Did this make my question more clear or do you need additional information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some slight variation of the below example should do it.  Without a slice of your data, it is tough to fit your current construct exactly, but this has all the elements that you are looking for.

To more clearly state what I mentioned in the comment, you must be repeating config information many many times in your data dictionary, which is a horrible practice.  I note in your example above that configuration 1318 is used many times.  Unless the *configuration itself* changes over time, pull it out.

Anyhow, the below uses a binary variable to capture and limit change by ASU and (as seen in graphic) walks down and up through lesser production configurations to meet the spikes at start and end.

##### CODE:

```
# Nitrogen Production

import pulp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# DATA
configs = { 'cfg-201' : (100, 0,   100),
            'cfg-73'  : (140, 40,  110),
            'cfg-108' : (50,  60,  60),
            'cfg-0'   : (0,   0,   0)}

tot_prod = {cfg:sum(vals) for cfg, vals in configs.items()}  # a convenience...

change_limit = 60  # max output change per ASU

demand = {  1: 210,
            2: 0,
            3: 0,
            4: 0,
            5: 0,
            6: 0,
            7: 275}

time_steps = list(demand.keys())

# make set of all time-config combos.
# note:  if there are restrictions to which combos are avail in particular times,
#        you could just make this as a dictionary from data
t_c = [ (t, c) for t in time_steps for c in configs ]

asus = [0, 1, 2]
t_a = [ (t, a) for t in time_steps for a in asus ]

prob = pulp.LpProblem("gas_production", pulp.LpMinimize)

# VARS
run_config = pulp.LpVariable.dicts('run', t_c, cat='Binary')            # run config c in time t
asu_output_increase = pulp.LpVariable.dicts('increase_asu', t_a, cat='Binary')  # asu a changes status in timeslot t

# OBJ: minimize total production
prob += pulp.lpSum(tot_prod[c] * run_config[t, c] for t, c in t_c)

# CONSTRAINTS

for t in time_steps:

    # 1. meet demand in all timesteps
    prob += pulp.lpSum(tot_prod[c] * run_config[t, c] for c in configs) >= demand[t]

    # 2. must run one of the configs (and only one) in each timestep
    prob += sum(run_config[t, c] for c in configs.keys()) == 1

# constraints for 2nd step and beyond
for t in time_steps[1:]:

    # 3. capture change in asu status, and limit it
    for asu in asus:
        prod_this_step = sum(configs[c][asu] * run_config[t, c] for c in configs)
        prod_last_step = sum(configs[c][asu] * run_config[t-1, c] for c in configs)
        prob += prod_this_step - prod_last_step <= asu_output_increase[t, asu] * change_limit
        prob += prod_last_step - prod_this_step <= (1 -  asu_output_increase[t, asu]) * change_limit


prob.solve()
# print(prob)
for v in prob.variables():
    if v.varValue > 0:
        print(v.name, "=", v.varValue)

plt.step(time_steps, [sum(tot_prod[c]*run_config[t, c].varValue for c in configs) for t in time_steps], where='mid', lw=3, label='supply')
plt.bar(time_steps, [demand[t] for t in time_steps], color='gray', label='demand')
plt.legend()
```

##### OUTPUT

Text output omitted...  the status is "optimal"

[image]

Comment: Hi AirSquid, many many thanks for helping me out. I appreciate it a lot. I have a dictionary in which all the unique configurations are stored with their ASU production config, electricity consumption and storage applications, similar to your configs dictionary with the structure { config number : [(ASU config), e cons, storage app] }. I used that dictionary to create the dictionary d, mentioned above the question, in which the timestep-configs combos are stored, similar to t_c in your code. In the dictionary d config information is repeated as a configuration is applicable at different times

Comment: So, just to make sure I understand you correctly and learn from this, I should just make the time-config combos and acces the specific information of the configs in another dictionary instead of also storing it in the combo as well. Because that would make the program a lot slower(?) because excessive information is stored and that is what you mean by horrible practice? or is there another (additional) reason?

Comment: Well, I'm inferring a few things because you didn't post too much of your data structure, but let me ask this:  How many instances of the specific details (the ASU outputs) for Configuration 1318 are in your dictionary?

Comment: Well, within dictionary d it will be there in each timeslot where config 1318 meets the demand's prerequisite.. of which I now understand its excessiveness :)

Comment: awesome.  yeah, putting many copies of the same details in many places is a recipe for disaster and a total PITA to maintain.  I would think 2 dictionaries just for the ASU piece.  One for the config details, and if there are restrictions on which configs are legal in which time slots, another that holds those pairings.  Anyhow, that is a sidebar for the issue of getting the constraints working fine.

Comment: I've applied your code to my problem and posted it above. I've also added a part of my configuration dictionary. I've added the constraint that the total amount of extraction and injection is 0 over the day, but then the problem is infeasible. Also, would you mind explaining how the asu_output_increase variable works? Additionally, I don't think the constraint regarding the ramping speed/ASU change works adequately as it should only be applied if the ASU was 'on' in the current stage and the previous stage while being allowed to turn 'on' or 'off', exceeding the limit.

Comment: I think if I add a binary variable which tracks the 'on/off' status of the ASU at time t, the constraint to limit the change in ASU I previously added should work. The difference in your code is that you accumulate the production values of the ASU, but it's about the  change of the discrete units which should be limited.

Comment: I have adjusted the code in the question with my current one. I've added a binary variable to track the on/off status of the ASU and use it to limit the change in production adequately. Many thanks for helping and showing me the light. The code is (in my novice opinion) much clearer and efficient thanks to you :D Have a nice day